# Ruby-wordnet - can not create lexicon

Tags: ruby, nlp, wordnet

I am trying out Ruby-Wordnet. I can require it in console, but then when I try to create a lexicon, I get an error:

```
   $ lex = WordNet::Lexicon.new
    TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
    from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/wordnet-0.0.5/lib/wordnet/lexicon.rb:93:in `%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when trying to install the wordnet gem. It seems to be triggered when running with $DEBUG on.

I had to fiddle quite a bit to get it running properly. I collected the steps I took, installing WordNet, the bdb gem, the wordnet gem and running the conversion script, in this gist.

https://gist.github.com/1779371

If you already have everything else running and just want to overcome this error that you're seeing you should be able to initialize it like this instead. This bypasses the bug on line 93 in lexicon.rb.

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'wordnet'
lex = WordNet::Lexicon.new(WordNet::Lexicon::DEFAULT_DB_ENV, 0444)
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out today!

Answer (score 0):

If requiring it and then attempting to create a new instance is really all you're doing before getting the error, the issue is almost certainly with how you've set up the database it [needs to work](http://deveiate.org/code/ruby-wordnet/README.html). You *did* set up the database, right? Also, depending on your setup, it could be that running it from the console (where your $PATH is likely somewhat different) is causing the database to be invisible; try running it from an actual file.

Comment: well I had berkley-db installed both through homebrew and as a gem. Is there anything extra I should do?  running from actual file returns same error. Thanks for answer )